# Autoloading Zend Framework classes

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

Here I am getting this error whenI tried to run a downloaded  zend project
 what is this error and how it can be solved

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\public\index.php on line 18
```

index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `index.php` and also detail where the Zend Framework is installed and which version?

Comment: that's the `index.php` file (which is vanilla ZF anyway). Where is the Zend Framework installed, which version and is it referenced on your `php.ini` include path?

Comment: include_path = “.;C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library” version:ZendFramework-1.11.7

Comment: According to your include path, this file should be located here: `C:/xampp/php/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application.php`  Can you verify it exists?

Comment: @Arun Have you restarted Apache since making changes to `php.ini`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Zend Framework "library" on your include path. You can either do this globally in your `php.ini` file's `include_path` directive or more simply in your application's `index.php` file, eg

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/path/to/zend/framework/library',
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()
)));
```

If it's a standard ZF app, there will probably already be something like that in `index.php`, just add the ZF path to the array.

If you do make any changes to your `php.ini` file, don't forget to restart Apache.

Comment: I had included the script you have provided but still It is not working

Comment: @Arun Silly question but is the Zend Framework installed at the nominated path?

Comment: As you know the XAMPP has got support for the Zend frame work. Is it necessary to install it? (I am a baby in the case ofPHP and ZEND)

Comment: @Arun XAMPP does not come bundled with Zend Framework. You would have to install it yourself.

Comment: OKEY  In case I use the Zend Server Community edition what I have to do to run a simple project?

Comment: @Arun Zend Server CE should work as it *does* bundle the Zend Framework and automatically puts it on the include path. IMO it is also the best *AMP package around so you won't regret switching. If you want to stick with XAMPP, installing the Zend Framework is trivial. You download it, unzip and apply my solution above pointing to the location of the "library" folder.

Comment: Yes I had installed the zend frmae work to xampp. Problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is telling you it can't find the needed files.

Have you added Zend library to your include path as [recommended in the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html)?

Comment: yes I have included the Zend Library path but it is not working.

Comment: It seems the choices are either you fix your include path settings or use a snippet like shown below.  Or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../php/ZendFramework/library')
```

Things don't happen by magic. You have to provide the correct include_path. From what I see (`C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\public\index.php`) you have to go two directories back to `C:\xampp`  and then up again into your library.

Comment: That's for the app's "library" folder, ie custom classes. It looks like it should work as the framework is referenced in the `php.ini` `include_path`